# Update rows on the basis of another row in the same table

Tags: mysql

I've got a table which looks something like this

```
id   |game_id| player_id| winner 
----------------------------
 1   |   1   |  1       |    
 2   |   1   |  2       |
 3   |   1   |  3       |
 4   |   1   |  4       |
```

i have a game_id and winner id , i wanna update winner as 1 and loser as 0;

```
UPDATE tournament SET winner = '1' WHERE game_id= 1 AND  player_id = 1
```

then

```
UPDATE tournament SET winner = '0' WHERE game_id= 1 AND  player_id != 1
```

OUTPUT

```
id   |game_id| player_id| winner 
----------------------------
 1   |   1   |  1       |    1
 2   |   1   |  2       |    0
 3   |   1   |  3       |    0
 4   |   1   |  4       |    0
```

can anyone tell me how it can be done using single query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE tournament SET winner = IF(player_id = 1, '1', '0') WHERE game_id= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Query

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2edee/3)**:

```
UPDATE tournament 
SET winner = CASE WHEN player_id = 1
                  THEN '1'
                  ELSE '0'END
WHERE game_id= 1
```

Comment: Sir i need some help, can u please answer my question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535591/getting-hierarchy-data-from-mysql-tables-and-optimize-code